# Fastest way to append a string to a text file w/o impact(effect) on web site load time

Tags: python, python-2.7, filesystems, mod-wsgi

Suppose my web site needs to run this python code 
for everytime it loads..

```
f = open('/aaa', 'a')
f.write('test' + '\n')
```

all it does is.. "append" .. "test" to "/a" file.

but perhaps there is a way to run this command without having impact on the web site load time.

perhaps it can be forked ?

but the only way to do that would be to.. use

```
import os
os.popen()
```

which sounds like can make things even more heavy.

based on my understanding.. things such as "APACHE".. 
 can append lines to files such as error_log at amazing speeds.

and i think i read somewhere that apache actually appends lines to error_log and 
access_log without even opening those files.

is there a way to do things that way from a python script ?

Comment: `os.popen("echo string>>/path/file &")` will append to file in background, but I don't think doing so in python will have big impact on load time..

Comment: If my answer helps, please confirm it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put these file IO operations into another thread in your main process.
Just execute this Python script in another thread paralleled.
If your main process is written by Python, try to use `threading` module. Hope it helps.